# How do i clone work from the master branch to a new one?

Tags: git, github

I've been working on the master branch. Now i want to pull all the work to a new branch i just created to continue working there.

Im new on git, and the idea is to work on a branch and just merge it on master until my code pass(im on school). But i already started and had made lots of progress that i dont want to lose.

I already git checkout  but it just returns me a blank readme.

Comment: If "git checkout" "just returns ... a blank readme", that means there's nothing on the master branch, except the apparent initial commit with the readme. This, of course, cannot be reconciled with the claims that you've been "working on the master branch". You will need to provide a better explanation of the current state of your git repository, and what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please share the command and output. Are you trying to checkout on different sytem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I can imagine that you're working on the master branch, but it seems that you haven't added changes and you haven't created any commit ( I guest only )
In that case, you can just create a new branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

In case you committed your work into commits in master branch and already pushed it to Github (ignore below commands if you haven't), you can back to master branch reverse it

```
git checkout master 
git reset --hard HEAD~HERE_NUMBER_OF_YOUR_NEW_COMMITS
git push origin master -f
git checkout new_branch_name #To continue work on new branch (with all your new works remained)
```

Then, commit changes ( this should be repeated many times when you have completed sth

```
git add .
git commit -m "I created new feature"
git push new_branch_name
```

And then, from Github, you can create a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request) so your tutor / teammate can review

Comment: I worked in master too and wanted to move my changes to a branch, so I simply unstaged my changes and simply did the one-liner to checkout a new_branch. Works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If the last few commits done on master should have been done on a feature branch instead, you can:

- create a feature branch
- reset master to where it should have been

That is:

```
m--m--m--f--f--f (master)

git checkout -b feature
git push -u origin feature

m--m--m--f--f--f (master, feature)

git checkout master
git reset --hard @~3 # make sure you don't have any pending modification
                     # this reset 3 commits back: adapt to your case
```

If you had already pushed master, you might need to `git push --force`.
If you are several working on the same repository, do communicate first before force pushing any branch.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create new branch from master branch. Everything from master branch will be available on new branch.